# JS regex match zero or more optional start with key words

Tags: javascript, regex

Given string like `keydown.capture.once.prevent.shift.control[arrowdown,arrowup]:silent` I want to match `shift.control[arrowdown,arrowup]:silent`

And if the same `keydown.capture.once.prevent.shift[arrowdown,arrowup]:silent` then it should match `shift[arrowdown,arrowup]:silent`

Here the keywords **shift | control** are optional, ex: `keydown.capture.once.prevent.[arrowdown,arrowup]:silent`, matching string `[arrowdown,arrowup]:silen`

I wrote the below regex, it can only capture zero or one keyword, but the expected result is zero or all keywords matching into separate group

`(shift|control)?\[(.*?)\]:silent`, how can we capture all the keywords if they exist?

Additional notes: Order of keywords doesn't matter, ex it can be `control.shift[]:silent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use any one of these regex solutions:

```sh
(?:(?:shift|control)\.?)*\[([^\]]*)\]:silent
```

This matches `shift` or control` optionally followed by a dit and repeats this non-capture group 0 or more times.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SpkG0N/1)

```sh
(?:shift(?:\.control)?|control(?:\.shift)?)?\[([^\]]*)\]:silent
```

This one matches `shift.control` OR `control.shift` in an *optional* non-capture group with the parts after dot optional in each alternation.

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/SpkG0N/4)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
(?:(shift|control|shift\.control|control\.shift))?(\[.*\]):silent
```

Test and output: https://regex101.com/r/rMSd2l/1